# template matching in objective -c using openCV

Tags: objective-c, xcode, opencv

I have used the following code for pattern recognition . But it is giving the false matching result . Please help me what is wrong in it . This is written in xcode .

```
Mat img_display;
img.copyTo( img_display );

/// Create the result matrix
int result_cols =  img.cols - templ.cols + 1;
int result_rows = img.rows - templ.rows + 1;

result.create( result_cols, result_rows, CV_32FC1 );

/// Do the Matching and Normalize
matchTemplate( img, templ, result, 5 );
normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

/// Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
double minVal; double maxVal; Point minLoc; Point maxLoc;
Point matchLoc;

minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );


/// For SQDIFF and SQDIFF_NORMED, the best matches are lower values. For all the other methods, the higher the better
if( match_method  == CV_TM_SQDIFF || match_method == CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED )
{
    matchLoc = minLoc;
    printf("fsf");
}
else
{
    matchLoc = maxLoc;
    printf("fsf2");
}

/// Show me what you got
rectangle( img_display, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );
//rectangle( result, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );

//imshow( image_window, img_display );
//imshow( result_window, result );

return img_display;
```

Thanks in advance . I have attached the screenshot here[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by saying **false matching result**?

Comment: hey Astor please look at the Edited question . Thank you

Comment: And what is your template ? Furthermore, how come you expect to never get wrong results with this approach ? Is it just because the function is named `matchTemplate` that it magically is always right ? Using ready packages without knowing what is going on makes me sad.

Comment: Please look at my edited question . I have added the template image

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

you should replace result.create( result_cols, result_rows, CV_32FC1 );
with  result.create(result_rows, result_cols,  CV_32FC1 );